# List all window names in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics

I’m learning Swift. How do I fix the following code to list the window names?

```swift
import CoreGraphics

let windows = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(CGWindowListOption.optionAll, kCGNullWindowID)
for i in 0..<CFArrayGetCount(windows) {
  if let window = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(windows, i) {
    print(CFDictionaryGetValue(window, kCGWindowName))
  }
}
```

The error:

```
main.swift:6:32: error: cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeRawPointer' to expected argument type 'CFDictionary?'
    print(CFDictionaryGetValue(window, kCGWindowName))
                               ^~~~~~
                                      as! CFDictionary
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It becomes easier if you avoid using the Core Foundation types and methods, and bridge the values to native Swift types as early as possible.

Here, `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()` returns an optional `CFArray` of `CFDictionaries`, and that can be bridged to the corresponding Swift type `[[String : Any]]`. Then you can access its values with the usual Swift methods (array enumeration and dictionary subscripting):

```
if let windowInfo = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(.optionAll, kCGNullWindowID) as? [[ String : Any]] {
    for windowDict in windowInfo {
        if let windowName = windowDict[kCGWindowName as String] as? String {
            print(windowName)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On Swift 4.2.1: (`warning: cast from 'CFArray?' to unrelated type '[[String : AnyObject]]' always fails`) and (`error: cannot convert value of type 'CFString' to type 'String' in coercion`)

Comment: @ShaunLebron I tested the code in Xcode 10.2(Swift 5) where it compiles and runs without warnings. I can check it with Swift 4.2 later. – Btw, there is no [[String : AnyObject]] in that code, did you copy it exactly?

Comment: Thanks, I’m running from command line with `swift build`.  reproducible here: https://github.com/shaunlebron/listwindows-swift

Comment: Found the problem. I have to use `import Cocoa` instead of `import CoreGraphics`.  It also works for `import Foundation` or `import Quartz`, but I don’t know why.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unsafeBitCast(_:to:)` to convert the opaque raw pointer to a `CFDictionary`. Note that you'll also need to convert the second parameter, to a raw pointer:

```swift
CFDictionaryGetValue(unsafeBitCast(window, to: CFDictionary.self), unsafeBitCast(kCGWindowName, to: UnsafeRawPointer.self))
```

[unsafeBitCast(_:to:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641250-unsafebitcast) tells the compiler to treat that variable as another type, however it's not very safe (thus the `unsafe` prefix), recommending to read the documentation for more details, especially the following note:

> Warning
>
> Calling this function breaks the guarantees of the Swift type system; use with extreme care.

In your particular case there should not be any problems using the function, since you're working with the appropriate types, as declared in the documentation of the `Foundation` functions you're calling.

Complete, workable code could look something like this:

```swift
import CoreGraphics

let windows = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(CGWindowListOption.optionAll, kCGNullWindowID)
for i in 0..<CFArrayGetCount(windows) {
    let windowDict = unsafeBitCast(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(windows, i), to: CFDictionary.self)
    let rawWindowNameKey = unsafeBitCast(kCGWindowName, to: UnsafeRawPointer.self)
    let rawWindowName = CFDictionaryGetValue(windowDict, rawWindowNameKey)
    let windowName = unsafeBitCast(rawWindowName, to: CFString?.self) as String?
    print(windowName ?? "")
}
```

**Update**
You can bring the CoreFoundation array sooner to the Swift world by casting right from the start:

```swift
let windows = CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(CGWindowListOption.optionAll, kCGNullWindowID) as? [[AnyHashable: Any]]
windows?.forEach { window in
    print(window[kCGWindowName])
}
```

The code is much readable, however it might pose performance problems, as the cast to [[AnyHashable: Any]]` can be expensive for large array consisting of large dictionaries.

Comment: This prints “__NSCFString” for every window instead of the window name.

Comment: @ShaunLebron which Xcode/Swift versions are you using? The code prints the window names on Xcode 10.2/Swift 4.2

Comment: Apple Swift version 4.2.1 (swiftlang-1000.11.42 clang-1000.11.45.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0. Xcode 10.1, Build version 10B61

Comment: @ShaunLebron, you can try adding a ` as String?` after the initialization code for `windowName`, this might fix the problem. I also updated the answer with this part.