# How do I get currently focused window title using Swift 5 in macOS Catalina?

Tags: swift

I am trying to write a program using swift 5. This is my first swift program. Also I can't find any example code of getting focused window's title in macOS using swift 5. I'd be appreciated if anyone help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Don't ask me how, but ask Apple Script what it can do to get the top most window and its PID or whatever.

Comment: You may also get that from `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo`?  I don't know.  Who knows!?

Comment: Thanks, El Tomato. Is there any code using Swift 5?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List all window names in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55662093/list-all-window-names-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks, DarkDust. But is there any module for checking if the windows is currently focused?